# Jest cannot import TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, lit-element

When executing a sample test, I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
```

I have the following file structure:

```
│
├── ...
├── src
│   └── ts
│       └── index.ts
├── test
│   └── ts
│       └── index.test.ts
├── ...
```

In my `jest` configuration, I have the following:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

In `index.ts`, I have the following class being exported:

```js
import {LitElement, html, customElement, property} from 'lit-element';

@customElement('hello-world')
class HelloWorld extends LitElement {
    @property({type: String}) title: string = "default title";
    @property({type: String}) description: string = "default description";

    render() {
        return html`
        <style>
        .container {
            padding: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #c8e7fd;
        }
        .container h1 {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>${this.title}</h1>
        <p>${this.description}</p>
        </div>
        `;
    }
}

export {
    HelloWorld
};
```

Lastly, in `index.test.ts`, I am importing the file as follows:

```js
import {HelloWorld} from "../../src/ts";

describe('Very first test', () => {
  it('A test', () => {
    const temp: HelloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    expect(temp).not.toBe(null);
  });
});
```

Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: In that src folder, do you by any chance have a ts.js as well as a ts.ts?  You should only have the ts.ts file.  The ts.js would be found and used first if it exists.

Comment: I only have *.ts files located in src

Comment: You could try removing the "preset" option.  I only have the "transform" entry and it's working.

Comment: That still did not work for me. Interestingly, when I modified my `index.ts` file to a much simpler example, it now worked. I am wondering if `jest` does not like the use of @decorators? I've updated the question with my code.

Comment: Provide your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: I've added my `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Oh, your issue is with `"target": "ESNext"`.  It transpiles the TypeScript to JS that is too new and jest can't understand it.  Try `"target": "es6"`

Comment: add `"test/**/*"` to tsconfig's include array

Comment: Adding `"test/**/*"` inside of `tsconfig.json` did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `lit-element` and `lit-html` were not being transpiled properly inside of `node_modules`. As a solution, I have the following configuration:

`babel.config.json`

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "decoratorsBeforeExport": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

`jest.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!(lit-element|lit-html)/)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: the transform pattern either doesn't need the '?' or maybe should have '(j|t)sx?' to say that the 'x' is optional if jsx is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
"target": "ESNext"
```

to

```
"target": "ES6"
```

What's happening is that TypeScript is transpiling into JS that's too modern for Jest to understand.  If there's still an issue you could try ES5 as well.